# Como haria paraMostar cantidad de productos vendidos en los meses de verano(enero-marzo)de todos los años (del 2000 a 2006)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: sql-server]

Mostar cantidad de productos vendidos  en los meses de verano(enero-marzo)de todos los años (del 2000 a 2006).

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imágenes con el SQL, publica directamente tu código y datos de ejemplo como parte de la pregunta (copiar y pegar el texto).

Comment: Tu consulta de por sí ya tiene un problema, le faltan los argumentos de los JOIN. ¿Cuales son los id´s  que relacionan cada tabla? ¿Podrías corregir esto y agregar el código como texto? Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte de las funciones `month` (mes) y `year` (año), para establecer un filtro.

Primero, su uso básico:

```
select   year(fecha) anio
       , month(fecha) mes
  from (      
        select cast('20180101' as date) Fecha
     ) a
```

Ahora, cómo filtrar, en tu caso, sería algo como:

```
select *
  from venta v
 where year(v.fecha) between 2000 and 2006
   and month(v.fecha) between 1 and 3 /* enero a marzo */
```

El resto de la adaptación en tu caso particular, queda a ejercicio del lector.

Answer (score 1):

te comento que debes hacer un group by, no tengo donde probar la consulta, la realicé en oracle y me funcionó, al convertirla para SQLServer sería lo siguiente:

```
ORACLE

    SELECT to_char(fecha_documento,'yyyy-mm') FECHA, nombre_producto "NOMBRE PRODUCTO", cantidad "CANTIDAD PRODUCTO"
      FROM venta_detalle vd, producto pr, venta ve
     WHERE to_char(fecha_documento,'yyyy') BETWEEN '2000' AND '2006'
       AND to_char(fecha_documento,'mm') between '01' AND '03'
  GROUP BY to_char(fecha_documento,'yyyy-mm')
  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

SQLSERVER

```
SELECT      [fech_ven] AS fecha, [nomb_pro] AS tipo_producto, [cant_pro_ven] AS cantidad_producto
FROM        [dbo].[Venta_Detalle]ve_de, [dbo].[Producto]pr, [dbo].[Venta]ve
WHERE       year([fech_ven]) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2006
AND         month([fech_ven]) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY    [fech_ven], [nomb_pro], [cant_pro_ven]
ORDER BY    [fech_ven] ASC;
```

como tienes muy escueto tu ejemplo, te muestro lo que me funcionó, cualquier adicional a la orden

Saludos cordiales